# Data is not deleting in laravel-5.7

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.7

hi m working on a project in Laravel-vue and wants to delete data using sweetalert but when I click on it then nthing happens, during npm run watch it shows this error:

```
  Errors compiling template:

  avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "delete"
  Raw expression: @click="delete"

     34 |                        /
     35 |                        &nbsp;
     36 |                        <a href="#" @click="delete">
        |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     37 |                          <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
     38 |                        </a>

    @ ./resources/js/components/Users.vue?vue&type=template&id=30c27aa6& 1:0-209 1:0-209
    @ ./resources/js/components/Users.vue
    @ ./resources/js/app.js
```

code:

```
  <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(user.id)">
                  <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
              </a>


  deleteUser(id){
       Swal.fire({
              title: 'Are you sure?',
             text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
             type: 'warning',
             showCancelButton: true,
             confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
             cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
             confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
           }).then((result) => {

           //send request to the server

             this.form.delete('api/user/'+id).then(()=>{
                 Swal.fire(
                   'Deleted!',
                   'Your file has been deleted.',
                   'success'
                    )
              }).catch(()=>{
                  swal("Failed!", "There was something worng.", "warning");
              });

            })

     },
```

how to solve this issue

Comment: Seems like your error is not related to the code you posted. You have `deleteUser` method, and error is about `delete`

Comment: how to solve this?

Comment: Re-check your question first, please

Comment: would to prefer to tell me how to fix it? or what should I do now